# Get the drive letter by doing right click on them

Tags: c#

I need to get the drive letter(Like "C:", "E:") in a message box by doing right-click on them and selecting my application's name appeared among the right-click menu items.

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: Which part of code exactly? because the codes huge

Comment: The parts needed so people can understand and see you problem in order to help you.

Comment: ACB do you know anything about this?

Comment: I tried editing this post. But Cant understand what you mention here. I need to learn some more English I think. Better, you seperate introduction and Problem.